# data extraction from web

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, data-extraction

I am planning to do a data extraction from web sources (web scraping) as part of my work. I would like to extract info around my company's 10km radius.

I would like to extract information such as condominiums, its address, number of units and its price per sqft. Other things like number of schools and kindergarten in the area and hotels.

I understand I need to extract from few sources/webpages. I will also be using Python.

I would like to know which library or libraries should I be using. Is web scraping the only means? Can we extract info from Google Maps?

Also, if anyone has any experience I will really appreciate if you can guide me on this.

Thanks a lot, guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Google Maps, try the API. Using web scraping tools for Maps data extraction is highly discouraged by Google TOS.

If you are using Python, it has very nice libraries BeautifulSoup and Scrapy for this purpose.

Other means? You can extract POIs from OSM data, try the open source tools. Property Info? May be it's available for your county / state from Govt Office, give it a try.